# Prevent accidental button presses on watch

Tags: technology

I use a digital watch; at the moment, I have one that hangs down from the belt loop on a pair of jeans, but I have the same issue with wristwatches - buttons will accidentally get pressed as I move around, bend over, or do various exercises, and unintended things will happen (e.g., setting an alarm for 1:00 am).

How might I prevent these buttons from getting pressed accidentally?  Ideally, I wouldn't prevent use of the buttons entirely, since I need them in order to, for instance, adjust for daylight savings time, but not of them need used terribly often.

I've searched for some sort of case that I could wrap around it, but haven't found anything.  Some sort of DIY solution could do it (for example, covering the buttons with resin), but I'm not sure how I would go about it without permanently preventing access to the buttons.

Comment: Does the device have a 'lock' function that involves, say, a long press on one or more buttons?

Answer (score 4):

Cut a disc from art board or stiff plastic about one-half inch larger diameter than the watch. Use a double-sided mounting tape to stick it to the back of the watch. It can be removed at any time when needed. This gives a small "picture frame" around the watch, which prevents clothing, etc, from bumping the buttons.

Comment: Some like it fancy so you could use the pattern (shape, size, etc.)  that works most effectively to make the button-guard (bumper) from leather (with nice stitching?) or high tech stuff that will complement your personal style. +1 great idea John.

Answer (score 1):

For the wristwatch, my solution is way simpler: I wear it on my right wrist. This way the button is on the upper side and will not be pressed when you fold the hand. Wrist smart watches follow the same basic design as the analog ones, but in the old times, buttons were supposed to be pulled up and nothing would happen when you simply pressed them.
As for the pocket watch, the solution is even simpler: don't keep it in your pocket unless you have some kind of case for it.

Answer (score 0):

Out of Harm's Way Lifehack:

Change the position of the watch—use a different belt loop, say.
Small differences could make a big difference in the mis-/alignment of the watch buttons and pressure points of your clothing.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> I've searched for some sort of case that I could wrap around it, but haven't found anything

Well, I've found: ([source](https://www.etsy.com/il-en/listing/982698422/tactical-military-smartwatchwatch))

[image: watch cover]

It a watch "cover" rather than "case" that's why you probably didn't find it.

---

If you prefer to have the watch more readily available, I can offer another hack: Pocket.

[image: watch inside pocket]

I don't mean use pocket watch, rather just simply put the watch, may it be wristwatch, smart watch, or anything else, inside a pocket of your jeans/trousers or even shirt.

This way chances of accidental button press is greatly reduced as the watch doesn't dangle.

Comment: I've actually found the opposite to be true...storing the watch in my pocket leads to far more accidental presses for me.

Answer (score 0):

A watch [cover](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=watch%20covers&iax=images&ia=images) or [pouch](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=watch%20pouch&iax=images&ia=images) might help you. There's a whole range of things to choose from. Some are made of leather, others very sturdy fabric.